# Error due to importing boto3: from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions failed

Tags: exception, import, openssl, cryptography, boto3

I download data from aws and use boto3. I have created an environment called per_env which has all my libraries, in which I conda installed all following libraries that are relevant to boto3:

`conda install --name per_env boto3`
`conda install --name per_env openssl`
`conda install --name per_env cryptography`

This is all happening in our Linux GPU server. However, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "get_plate_names.py", line 1, in 
import boto3
File "/home/papang/anaconda3/envs/per_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/boto3/**init**.py", line 17, in 
.....
.....
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import exceptions as rust_exceptions
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: Python API call failed

The (.....) dots above indicate several relevant to boto3, openssl and cryptography errors that I receive in the middle. Any ideas what goes wrong would be really helpful.

I tried to update conda to its latest version and re-install the following libraries in my environment:

`conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
`conda install --name per_env boto3`
`conda install --name per_env openssl`
`conda install --name per_env cryptography`

Still getting the same error as described above.

I am not sure I understand what is wrong there.